# The method 'Tap' isn't defined for the type 'TapScreen'

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm new at this world and still learning, this might be easy to u but it's not for me :(
I'm doing some coding on a test app and I got stuck at The TapBar Widget,
the message is:
The method 'Tap' isn't defined for the type 'TapScreen'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Tap'.dartundefined_method

```
class TapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TapScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tap (                             <===// The problem is here on (Tap).
                icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
                text: 'Skills',
              ),
              Tap(                             <===// The problem is here on (Tap).
                icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                text: 'Favorites',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            CategoriesScreen(),
            FavoritesScreen(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you define a widget Named Tap ? if yes you have to import it

Comment: Tab ---- Tap .....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that isn't imported in your file, or the widget doesn't exist,

If you need a Widget that recognize tap gesture, try InkWell or GestureDetector widget

```
 GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: YourCustomWidget()
  )
```

and same code should work for InkWell